# Does HuggingFace have a model for finding good paragraph boundaries?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Does HuggingFace have a model that, given a long text without any line breaks, would find good (according to some semantical measure) paragraph boundaries?

Comment: yes we can do it but you should codsider the Granularity / Context Dependency / Computationally Expensive / Lack of Structured Knowledge ... if you are trying to break up a long piece of text into paragraph-sized chunks, you would ideally want each paragraph to be cohesive and centered around a single topic . good paragraph boundaries are not solely determined by topic similarity. Stylistic factors, like the progression of an argument or the need for a pause, can also dictate where paragraph breaks should be.

Comment: @Ilya Yes, all these are considerations. But so far I am not aware of any existing model for solving the problem. What models are you aware of?

Comment: we have  several methods and models . but i dont know your data . you can use ... Topic Modeling Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) / TextTiling specifically designed for text segmentation / BERT-Based Models BERT and other transformer(...) models can be fine-tuned to perform text segmentation tasks i used bert for my task / Sequence Classification /  Paragraph Boundary Detection  and som methods ... Paragraph Segmentation with Hierarchical Attention Networks / Paragraph Boundary Detection by Wang . would you like to contact me

Comment: @Ilya Is there a model in HuggingFace that is already trained on English texts for this specific task (or one whose solution can be directly transformed into a solution for this task) and that I can try without further fine-tuning? You still have not replied to my comment about the model you suggested in your answer.

Comment: @Ilya Google search for "HuggingFace TextTiling" produces an interesting result, but when I go to the page, it's just a dataset...

Comment: Upvoting and accepting answers motivates me and I can help you more .use this  from nltk.tokenize import TextTilingTokenizer . You value my responsiveness ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254749/discussion-between-ilya-and-alwayslearning).

Comment: @Ilya I will happily upvote and accept an answer that addresses my question. I have upvoted your helpful comments and responded in the chat.